# How to change state in webpart.tsx from wepart.ts property pane - SPFx

Tags: web-part, modal-dialog, spfx-webparts, react

I am trying to add a button to my property pane that will pop up a modal where the user will be able to enter in an image to be displayed on my banner webpart which is just an image carousel.

I  currently have a PropertyPaneButton. I would like to set the value of the `onClick` key to a function as it's value that can setState within my webpart.tsx file allowing me to rerender the DOM. I have a stateful `banner.tsx` file that is holding my banner images for the carousel in an array.

My idea is that once the user clicks `add image` from the modal I'll be able to grab what's been entered in the text field, create a new object, and setState to have the DOM rerender with the new picture added to the carousel.

The issue seems to be that I am unable to link my webpart.ts file - where my property pane and add image button is, to my `webpart.tsx` file - where my state holding the images is.

Admittedly, I am new sharepoint framework and am having difficulties navigating the documentation for a possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here how I would do it:

1. Create a state variable that keeps track of whether to show/hide the dialog (e.g,: showCallout).
2. In your constructor, set the variable to false.
3. In your render method, conditionally wrap the dialog rendering code. E.g.:
   { this.state.showDialog ?  : null }

The awesome [sp-dev-fx-property-controls](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-property-controls) library uses a similar trick with their property controls, except that they use the [Office UI fabric Callout controls](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/callout). Check out the code at https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/blob/f66083ed4b760dd8a4e28789f7bbcbed3249dfa9/src/common/placeholderWithCallout/PlaceholderWithCallout.tsx.

I hope I understood your question properly and this helps?

Good luck!